# In this onClick Slider last slide goes to first slide without clicking and animation

Tags: slider, jquery-animate

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 //configerations
 var width = 720;
 var animationSpeed = 700;
 var currentSlide = 1;
 //DOM items
 var $slider = $('#slider');     //main sliding div
 var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides'); //ULs
 var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide'); // LIs
 
 
  $slider.click(function() {
   $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-=720px'},animationSpeed, function() {
   currentSlide++;
   if (currentSlide == $slides.length) {
   currentSlide = 1;
   $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0); }
   });
  });
 });
```

```css
 #slider {width:720px; height:400px; overflow:hidden; float:left; border: 1px solid black;}
 #slider .slides {display: block; width:6000px; height:400px; margin:0; padding:0;}
 #slider .slide {float:left; list-style-type:none; width:720px; height:400px;}
```

```html
 <div id="slider">
 <ul class="slides">
 <li class="slide">111</li>
 <li class="slide">222</li>
 <li class="slide">333</li>
 <li class="slide">444</li>
 <li class="slide">555</li>
 <li class="slide">666</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

In this onClick Slider, it works fine upto the last slide and then without clicking it goes to first slide.

Please see the following Link:
[Please see this Link to check the slider](http://neec.edu.pk/new.html)

Comment: I think changing the `if` clause from `currentSlide == $slides.length` to `currentSlide > $slides.length` should solve your problem. Basically, to check if `currentSlide` is _greater than_ number of slides and only then set `currentSlide` to `1` and set `$slideContainer`'s `margin-left` to `0`.

Comment: Thanks Tahir, it is working now but from slide 6 to 1 it is not properly animating. from Slide 6 it animates to a blank slide and then blank slide changes to slide 1 right after completing the animation. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, the original problem i.e. `$slideContainer` moving to the *first* slide as soon as the *last* slide becomes active (which is the `li` element containing `666`) can be resolved by simply changing the original `if` condition from `currentSlide == $slides.length` to `currentSlide > $slides.length`.

But, as you had noticed, it still does a sudden jump to the *first* slide. To solve this, you may have to re-think how the `$slideContainer` should be animated.

Originally, we were checking for a specific condition *after* the sliding animation has completed. But my proposal would be to check for a condition even *before* an animation has started.

What I am trying to say is that if you change your JS to look like the below, it should produce your desired result.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = 720;
  var animationSpeed = 700;
  var currentSlide = 1;
  var prevSlide;
  var $slider = $('#slider');
  var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
  var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

  $slider.click(function() {
    prevSlide = currentSlide;
    if (prevSlide === $slides.length) {
        currentSlide = 1;
        $slideContainer.stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left': 0}, animationSpeed);
    } else {
        currentSlide += 1;
        $slideContainer.stop(true, true).animate({'margin-left': '-=720px'}, animationSpeed);
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively, take a look at the **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/Lg1b41cm/)**.
Let me know if anything is unclear in the code above. Hope this produces the result you are looking for.

Comment: Once again thanks for your reply/help. In this last code above, when it goes to slide 6 then onClick it animates backward to slide 1. This is OK. But is it possible, if I click on slide 6.. it should go to slide 1 just like it is animating from slide 1 to 2 and 3 and upto 6. I mean just as 1 is the next slide to 6? Otherwise, above code will work for me.

Comment: The thing is, you are animating a single container and not individual smaller slides. This container moves left and right on different conditions. It shouldn't keep on moving in one direction (which if you try to imagine, is what you are asking for).

Comment: To really achieve what you are looking for, I guess you will have to approach this problem in a very different way where you would be animating individual slides so that one can be moved independently of each other.

Comment: Tahir, I've found this method which worked exactly what I was looking for:

    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#slider ul").each(function(){
   // Set the interval to be 10 seconds
  // var t = setInterval(function(){
   $("#rightArrow").click(function(){
    $("#slider ul").animate({marginLeft:-360},1000,function(){
     // This code runs after the animation completes
     $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
     // Now we've taken out the left-most list item, reset the margin
     $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    })
   });
  });
 });

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Following method is doing exactly what I was looking for in the above question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#slider ul").each(function(){
        // Set the interval to be 10 seconds
    //  var t = setInterval(function(){
        $("#rightArrow").click(function(){
            $("#slider ul").animate({marginLeft:-360},1000,function(){
                // This code runs after the animation completes
                $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
                // Now we've taken out the left-most list item, reset the margin
                $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
            })
        });
    });
});
```